# React object is not a function error on useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

I am having issues when using the useEffect hook in this functional component. I get an object is not a function error.

I saw this error is often found in camelCase named functional components, however, this is a PascalCase named functional component.

Please let me know if you can spot the error. This is from an udemy tutorial on React, so please excuse my noobness :)

Edit: I confirm that when commenting out useEffect, the component is rendered without issues

Edit 2: In order to make sure that there isn't any syntax error, I created a toBeExecuted function which I would then pass as a parameter of useEffect(tried both only passing the method name, as well as calling it), and the error is still present

$ npm view react version
16.13.1

```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    
    import classes from "./Cockpit.css";
    
    const Cockpit = (props) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("shd");
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert("Saved data to cloud!");
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
          console.log('[Cockpit.js] cleanup work in use')
        }
      }, [props.persons]);
    
      const assignedClasses = [];
      let btnClass = "";
      if (props.showPersons) {
        btnClass = classes.Red;
      }
      
      if (props.persons.length <= 2) {
        assignedClasses.push(classes.red); // classes = ['red']
      }
      if (props.persons.length <= 1) {
        assignedClasses.push(classes.bold); // classes = ['red', 'bold']
      }
    
      return (
        <div className={classes.Cockpit}>
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <p className={assignedClasses.join(" ")}>This is really working!</p>
          <button className={btnClass} onClick={props.clicked}>
            Toggle Persons
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Cockpit;
```

Below is the console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Cockpit (Cockpit.js:6)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:10449)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:10647)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:12621)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:12730)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1319)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1358)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1215)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:12848)
    at scheduleUpdateImpl (react-dom.development.js:13233)
    at scheduleUpdate (react-dom.development.js:13172)
    at scheduleTopLevelUpdate (react-dom.development.js:13445)
    at Object.updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:13475)
    at react-dom.development.js:17168
    at Object.unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:13304)
    at renderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:17167)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:17192)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:669)
    at fn (bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:87)
    at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:108)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:669)
    at bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:715
    at bundle.js:719
```

Below is the browser error

```
×
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Cockpit
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/src/components/Cockpit/Cockpit.js:6
  3 | import classes from "./Cockpit.css";
  4 | 
  5 | const Cockpit = (props) => {
> 6 |   useEffect(() => {
  7 |     console.log("shd");
  8 |     setTimeout(() => {
  9 |       alert("Saved data to cloud!");
View compiled
mountIndeterminateComponent
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10449
  10446 | 
  10447 | {
  10448 |   ReactCurrentOwner$2.current = workInProgress;
> 10449 |   value = fn(props, context);
  10450 | }
  10451 | // React DevTools reads this flag.
  10452 | workInProgress.effectTag |= PerformedWork$1;
View compiled
beginWork
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10647
  10644 | 
  10645 | switch (workInProgress.tag) {
  10646 |   case IndeterminateComponent$2:
> 10647 |     return mountIndeterminateComponent(current, workInProgress, priorityLevel);
  10648 |   case FunctionalComponent$1:
  10649 |     return updateFunctionalComponent(current, workInProgress);
  10650 |   case ClassComponent$6:
View compiled
performUnitOfWork
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12621
  12618 | {
  12619 |   startWorkTimer(workInProgress);
  12620 | }
> 12621 | var next = beginWork(current, workInProgress, nextPriorityLevel);
  12622 | if (true && ReactFiberInstrumentation$1.debugTool) {
  12623 |   ReactFiberInstrumentation$1.debugTool.onBeginWork(workInProgress);
  12624 | }
View compiled
workLoop
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12730
  12727 | if (nextPriorityLevel <= TaskPriority$1) {
  12728 |   // Flush all synchronous and task work.
  12729 |   while (nextUnitOfWork !== null) {
> 12730 |     nextUnitOfWork = performUnitOfWork(nextUnitOfWork);
  12731 |     if (nextUnitOfWork === null) {
  12732 |       !(pendingCommit !== null) ? invariant(false, 'Should have a pending commit. This error is likely caused by a bug in React. Please file an issue.') : void 0;
  12733 |       // We just completed a root. Commit it now.
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1319
  1316 |   // nested call would trigger the fake event handlers of any call higher
  1317 |   // in the stack.
  1318 |   fakeNode.removeEventListener(evtType, callCallback, false);
> 1319 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
  1320 |   didError = false;
  1321 | }
  1322 | 
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1358
  1355 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  1356 | var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
  1357 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 1358 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
  1359 | 
  1360 | if (didError) {
  1361 |   if (!didSetError) {
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1215
  1212 |  * @param {...*} args Arguments for function
  1213 |  */
  1214 | invokeGuardedCallback: function (name, func, context, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
> 1215 |   invokeGuardedCallback.apply(ReactErrorUtils, arguments);
  1216 | },
  1217 | 
  1218 | /**
View compiled
performWork
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12848
  12845 | var didError = false;
  12846 | var error = null;
  12847 | {
> 12848 |   invokeGuardedCallback$1(null, workLoop, null, minPriorityLevel, deadline);
  12849 |   if (hasCaughtError()) {
  12850 |     didError = true;
  12851 |     error = clearCaughtError();
View compiled
scheduleUpdateImpl
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13233
  13230 |     performWork(SynchronousPriority$1, null);
  13231 |   } else {
  13232 |     // Flush both synchronous and task work.
> 13233 |     performWork(TaskPriority$1, null);
  13234 |   }
  13235 |   break;
  13236 | case TaskPriority$1:
View compiled
scheduleUpdate
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13172
  13169 | }
  13170 | 
  13171 | function scheduleUpdate(fiber, priorityLevel) {
> 13172 |   return scheduleUpdateImpl(fiber, priorityLevel, false);
  13173 | }
  13174 | 
  13175 | function scheduleUpdateImpl(fiber, priorityLevel, isErrorRecovery) {
View compiled
scheduleTopLevelUpdate
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13445
  13442 |     warning$18(callback === null || typeof callback === 'function', 'render(...): Expected the last optional `callback` argument to be a ' + 'function. Instead received: %s.', callback);
  13443 |   }
  13444 |   addTopLevelUpdate(current, nextState, callback, priorityLevel);
> 13445 |   scheduleUpdate(current, priorityLevel);
  13446 | }
  13447 | 
  13448 | return {
View compiled
updateContainer
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13475
  13472 |     container.pendingContext = context;
  13473 |   }
  13474 | 
> 13475 |   scheduleTopLevelUpdate(current, element, callback);
  13476 | },
  13477 | 
  13478 | 
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17168
  17165 |   root = container._reactRootContainer = newRoot;
  17166 |   // Initial mount should not be batched.
  17167 |   DOMRenderer.unbatchedUpdates(function () {
> 17168 |     DOMRenderer.updateContainer(children, newRoot, parentComponent, callback);
  17169 |   });
  17170 | } else {
  17171 |   DOMRenderer.updateContainer(children, root, parentComponent, callback);
View compiled
unbatchedUpdates
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13304
  13301 | isUnbatchingUpdates = isBatchingUpdates;
  13302 | isBatchingUpdates = false;
  13303 | try {
> 13304 |   return fn();
  13305 | } finally {
  13306 |   isBatchingUpdates = previousIsBatchingUpdates;
  13307 |   isUnbatchingUpdates = previousIsUnbatchingUpdates;
View compiled
renderSubtreeIntoContainer
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17167
  17164 |   var newRoot = DOMRenderer.createContainer(container);
  17165 |   root = container._reactRootContainer = newRoot;
  17166 |   // Initial mount should not be batched.
> 17167 |   DOMRenderer.unbatchedUpdates(function () {
  17168 |     DOMRenderer.updateContainer(children, newRoot, parentComponent, callback);
  17169 |   });
  17170 | } else {
View compiled
render
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17192
  17189 |   return renderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, true, callback);
  17190 | },
  17191 | render: function (element, container, callback) {
> 17192 |   return renderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, false, callback);
  17193 | },
  17194 | unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer: function (parentComponent, element, containerNode, callback) {
  17195 |   !(parentComponent != null && ReactInstanceMap_1.has(parentComponent)) ? invariant(false, 'parentComponent must be a valid React Component') : void 0;
View compiled
./src/index.js
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './containers/App';
   5 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App appTitle="Person Manager" />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | registerServiceWorker();
   9 | 
  10 | 
View compiled
__webpack_require__
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/webpack/bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:669
  666 | };
  667 | 
  668 | // Execute the module function
> 669 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
  670 | 
  671 | // Flag the module as loaded
  672 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/webpack/bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:87
  84 |      console.warn("[HMR] unexpected require(" + request + ") from disposed module " + moduleId);
  85 |      hotCurrentParents = [];
  86 |  }
> 87 |  return __webpack_require__(request);
  88 | };
  89 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  90 |  return {
View compiled
0
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63759:18
__webpack_require__
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/webpack/bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:669
  666 | };
  667 | 
  668 | // Execute the module function
> 669 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
  670 | 
  671 | // Flag the module as loaded
  672 | module.l = true;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/react course/module 7/debugging--01-finished/webpack/bootstrap 27db9ccab8c2fd790147:715
  712 | __webpack_require__.h = function() { return hotCurrentHash; };
  713 | 
  714 | // Load entry module and return exports
> 715 | return hotCreateRequire(0)(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
  716 | 
  717 | 
  718 | 
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:719:10
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "radium": "^0.19.4",
    "react": "^16.0.0-rc.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0-rc.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you confirm it works without useEffect?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that if I comment useEffect out, the component is rendered without issues

Comment: Can you create a sandbox sample with the reproduced error?

Comment: can we see your package.json?

Comment: sorry, just saw you had the React version posted - would still like to take a peek at the package.json. :)

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded the package.json code in the question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working in a Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow--useeffect-qzg3z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I lifted your `props` values above to constants for the sake of the demo. I invented values that weren't clear from your code.

My guess is that it's the value of your `props.clicked` in

```js
<button className={btnClass} onClick={props.clicked}>
```

Maybe `console.log(props.clicked)` and see what it's coming through as?

Edit: I tested by replacing `clicked` with `{}`, and it throws an error, but it's not the same error you're seeing. So, I think my hunch is wrong. Sorry :(

Another bug (probably unrelated) is that you're using capital "R" `classes.Red` and lowercase "r" `classes.red`. You didn't share that object so I'm not sure which is correct.

Lastly, a callout. You likely don't need to pass `props.persons` as a dependency array to the `useEffect`. Sometimes I want to force a re-render unrelated to the data being used, but it's pretty rare. Usually your dependency array revolves around the data being used inside of the `useEffect`, and you aren't using `props.persons`. I guess you're doing a tutorial, so maybe that will change.

Answer (score -1):

I manage to resolve this issue by upgrading my react to the latest version.

The link below is where I found the answer to resolving this issue:
https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/learn/lecture/13556300#questions/11954840